# how does CSipSimple connect to Ekiga through NAT?

Tags: applications, networking, voip, sip, router

What networking [magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) does [CSipSimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSipSimple) employ for [Ekiga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekiga) that it works behind a [Netgear](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/WNR1000v2) home router and NAT?  Jitsi [cannot](https://askubuntu.com/a/866942/45156) connect to Ekiga from behind a router.

Wikipedia says that it uses:

> NAT traversal using STUN, TURN and ICE

But which and how?  This is in the context of configuring Jitsi.